# Multiple Queries on Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

How to use multiple queries with parameters? 
i tried this without using parameters and it's working
please help me in my second query...
Please help..

edit: my "query2" is not working, Every time i add or insert, there's no data in my database table(history_pay) plain blank...

con.Open()

```
    Try
        cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO studentpay(id,student_name,course,year_level,semester,units,amount,orno,ordate,cashier,paymentfor,tuition,amountpay,balance) VALUES (@id,@student_name,@course,@year_level,@semester,@units,@amount,@orno,@ordate,@cashier,@paymentfor,@tuition,@amountpay,@balance)"


        ' this is my second query no inserting data
        query2 = "INSERT INTO history_pay (id,student_name,last_date,last_amountpaid,last_balance) VALUES (@id,@student_name,@ordate,@amount,@balance)"
        Dim QueryString As String = String.Concat(cmd, ";", query2)
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand(QueryString, con)


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudentid.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_name", txtstudentname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", cblcourse.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year_level", cblyear.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", cblsemester.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", txtunits.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", txtamountpay.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orno", txtorno.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordate", txtordate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashier", txtcashier.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentfor", cblpaymentfor.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuition", lbltuition.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amountpay", lblamountspay.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", lblbalance.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Sucessfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        load_data()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: no inserting data

Comment: Try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Your code just doesn't make sense.  Pick up a pen and paper and write down, step by step, what you need to do, then write code to do it. You create `QueryString` in a way that makes no sense, then you don't even use `command`. If you want to execute both statements together, why do you have two command objects in the first place?  Did you even look at what `QueryString` contained?

Comment: Since you never execute `command` I have no idea how you would expect it to insert data.

Comment: Its a different table with different parameters.  Run it as a second query. Read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how to use the site effectively

Comment: Don't leave your connection open like that.  Put every disposable object in a using block.  Just run two separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're table design looks erratic. I see repeating values in two different tables. You should look into the reference design.

Second, I suggest looking into an Object Reference Model (ORM) as it'll save you a ton of time while also giving you compile time checking. I consider it invaluable on larger projects with 50,000+ lines of code. You would need to learn LINQ, but I suggest learning LINQ anyway as it's a powerful tool for data mining and manipulation.

I suggest using Command.Parameters.Add instead of Command.Parameters.AddWithValue, however this is more of a personal preference since I use TSQL and I like fine control over the inputs.

I commend you for using parameters instead of a string concat. That helps avoid an injection attack.

As for your question, given the information you've provided, this is how I'd do it if I couldn't use an ORM and I couldn't make the table design more efficient.

```
Using MySQLSERVER_Connection As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("<Your Login Details>")
    Using MySQLCommand As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand()
        MySQLCommand.Connection = MySQLSERVER_Connection
        Dim Command As New Text.StringBuilder
        Command.AppendLine("INSERT INTO studentpay")
        Command.AppendLine("(id,student_name,course,year_level,semester,units,amount,orno,ordate,cashier,paymentfor,tuition,amountpay,balance)")
        Command.AppendLine("VALUES")
        Command.AppendLine("(@id,@student_name,@course,@year_level,@semester,@units,@amount,@orno,@ordate,@cashier,@paymentfor,@tuition,@amountpay,@balance);")
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudentid.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_name", txtstudentname.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", cblcourse.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year_level", cblyear.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", cblsemester.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", txtunits.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", txtamountpay.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orno", txtorno.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordate", txtordate.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashier", txtcashier.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentfor", cblpaymentfor.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuition", lbltuition.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amountpay", lblamountspay.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", lblbalance.Text)
        MySQLSERVER_Connection.Open()
        MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MySQLSERVER_Connection.Close()
    End Using
    Using MySQLCommand As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand()
        MySQLCommand.Connection = MySQLSERVER_Connection
        Dim Command As New Text.StringBuilder
        Command.AppendLine("INSERT INTO history_pay")
        Command.AppendLine("(id,student_name,last_date,last_amountpaid,last_balance)")
        Command.AppendLine("VALUES")
        Command.AppendLine("(@id,@student_name,@ordate,@amount,@balance);")
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudentid.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_name", txtstudentname.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", txtamountpay.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordate", txtordate.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amountpay", lblamountspay.Text)
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", lblbalance.Text)
        MySQLSERVER_Connection.Open()
        MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MySQLSERVER_Connection.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

I'm using a single connection and two commands. Please note that I'm unable to test this code.

Comment: "MySQL libraries try to stop an injection attack by not allowing a second command to run" I run a second command after the semi-colon for `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` and it runs. Maybe this is version specific?

Comment: Last time I had the issue come up was about a decade ago. At the time I just decided to use multiple execution statements instead. Then again, I do remember being able to do an execution and then a select in the same command to get the last inserted ID number. I haven't really bothered with direct SQL in a .NET program these last three years since discovering ORMs. I tend to stick with database functions and procedures for anything really complicated. It might be an issue with parameters being used more than once in the statement. Try doing a double insert using the same parameters.

Comment: Tried it. Worked fine.

Comment: Removed false statement in regards to double command annihilation.